# Solving YACC shift/reduce. Driving me crazy

Tags: yacc

Hey Guys this is driving me crazy I'll list the error and the relevant code below. Thanks in advance for any help.

ERROR:

```
51: shift/reduce conflict (shift 69, reduce 28) on '{'
state 51
funcao : publico tIDENTIFIER '(' seq_vars ')' eqliteral . corpo  (13)
corpo : .  (28)

'{'  shift 69
$end  reduce 28
tVOID  reduce 28
tPUBLIC  reduce 28
tCONST  reduce 28
tIF  reduce 28
tDO  reduce 28
tFOR  reduce 28
tCONTINUE  reduce 28
tBREAK  reduce 28
tRETURN  reduce 28
tINTEGER  reduce 28
tNUMBER  reduce 28
tSTRING  reduce 28

corpo  goto 70
bloco  goto 71
```

And this is the relevant code

```
// Função
funcao: publico tIDENTIFIER '(' seq_vars ')' eqliteral corpo {};
// Corpo do bloco
corpo: bloco |;
// Bloco
bloco:  '{' seq_decls seq_inst '}' {/*figure this out later*/};
```

I'll keep trying to solve it and post the answer if I do.

Comment: We need to see your entire `.y` file to have any hope of helping.

Comment: Why the empty rule in the `corpo` nonterminal?

Comment: The empty alternative in `corpo` (where it says `corpo: bloco | /* Nothing */;` except that the comment is missing) is the source of the trouble.

Comment: the entire .y file was too large to be there imo
uploaded it here http://pastebin.com/qZdZZECt if you wanna take a look. And this last alternative solved nothing. Ty for all your help

Comment: Also the code works fine with 
corpo: bloco; 
except corpo is an optional parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since we can't possible replicate the circumstances, I'm only guessing...

It looks like Yacc doesn't know what to do when it reaches the position after the `eqliteral` nonterminal. You can see that's where the parser generator is because of the `.` in rule in the error message.

When Yacc reaches this position, and there is no `'{'` terminal, should it shift using the `bloco` rule (you see the `.` in that rule too) or should it reduce when seeing something else?

One possible solution (that I'm unable to verify) is to change the `funcao` rule:

```
funcao: publico tIDENTIFIER '(' seq_vars ')' eqliteral
      | publico tIDENTIFIER '(' seq_vars ')' eqliteral '{' seq_decls seq_inst '}'
      ;
```

It *may* work, it may not.

Comment: Changing that perse lead me to the exact same thing. In order to solve it I had to change the eqliteral. Im marking this as the right answer as soon as I can. Tkx